# How to align div components in one line?

Tags: css

The result I want looks like this

[image]

What I have currently

[image]

So all I want is the tag to be immediately after the title line. This small issue is one I am struggling

Relevant part of Render statement

```
<div className="headtitle">
              {items.product.name}
              <div className="flexbox-item-tag">{items.product.tags}</div>
            </div>
```

Items.product.name is the main title containing the drone title.
Items.product.tag is the tag that must follow the title

The css for the headtitle div which contains the title and tag.

```
.headtitle {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 526px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The tags class and styling css

```
.flexbox-item-tag {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(196, 193, 193, 0.274);
  border: #333333;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
  width: 111px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: or you can just use <span>s which are inline by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.flexbox-item-tag` should be set as `display: inline-block`.

The element is a `div`, therefore its default display is `block` which means it will render on its own "row", "below" the previous element, as shown in your example.

Note that you've set `align-self` on the `.flexbox-item-tag` element, which cannot work without the parent element being set as [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div className="headtitle">
            <div> {items.product.name} </div>
            <div className="flexbox-item-tag">{items.product.tags} 
     </div>

.headtitle {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 526px;
  text-align: left;
  display:flex;
  margin-top: 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```